# Angular 2 passing html attributes from parent to child

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I want to pass attribute of HTML from parent to child. Is there any way where I can directly pass attribute from a parent without creating a variable for it in parent's .ts class and then passing it. Here is sample code of parent

```
<app-field-lable type="number"></app-field-lable>
```

and here is my field label component.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="signageRequest.brandingSpaceName"  class="form-control"/>
```

As you can see I am passing type="number" attribute from a parent, but it ain't working. I know the mechanism to create a variable in parent and then passing it to child via a @Input decorator. But is there a way where I do not have to create all of the variables in a parent class and pass it directly to a child.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put `string` as `@Input`:

```
<app-field-lable [inputType]="'number'"></app-field-lable>
```

Here is sample for Ts file and how you can use it in html

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-field-lable',
 template: '<input type="{{inputType}}"/>',
 styleUrls: ['./field-lable.component.css']
})
export class FieldLableComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() inputType:string;
 constructor() { }
 ngOnInit{}
}
```

Main idea, that native attributes (like `type`) expects strings, but `@Input()` attributes (like `[customAttr]`) expects variables

Comment: It is not working like this. I have tried to pass "number" directly but the input field rendered is not of type="number"

Comment: @HaseebWali I can't see `type` attribute on your `input`, do you noticed `'` single quotes inside `"` double while passing arguments? please, update your code to actual

Comment: if you passing `"number"` - you refer to `number` variable, you should pass string value `"'number'"`

Comment: Sorry for typeo. I have send " 'number' " as in single quotes, and it is being received as @Input() inputType properly, but problem is when i am using it on <input type="inputType"> this input element is not of number type.

Comment: @HaseebWali try `<input type="{{inputType}}">`

Comment: It worked man. Thanks. Please update the answer and also add on child component side we have to write like <input type="{{inputType}}"

Comment: Hello, how can I use [inputType] value in parent.component.ts like this 
search() {
 console.log(this.inputType)
}